# Ember.js ArrayController error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-testing

I am trying to test the following sample Ember.js code but I am always getting the following error displayed in the Chrome browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '_super' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Code:

```
MovieTracker.moviesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
       content: [],
       init: function(){
           this._super();
           var list = [
               MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                   title: 'Movie 1',
                   rating: 4 }),
               MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                   title: 'Movie 2',
                   rating: 5
               })];
           this.set('content', list);
       }
});
```

I am using Ember-1.3.2.js

can someone please tell me what I am missing here? and how to solve this error?

New error message after changing .create to .extend as recommended by @kingpin2k

> TypeError: Object function () { if (!wasApplied) { Class.proto(); //
>   prepare prototype... } o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY,
>   undefinedDescriptor); o_defineProperty(this, '_super',
>   undefinedDescriptor); var m = meta(this), proto = m.proto; m.proto =
>   this; if (initMixins) { // capture locally so we can clear the closed
>   over variable var mixins = initMixins; initMixins = null;
>   this.reopen.apply(this, mixins); } if (initProperties) { // capture
>   locally so we can clear the closed over variable var props =
>   initProperties; initProperties = null; var concatenatedProperties =
>   this.concatenatedProperties; for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l;
>   i++) { var properties = props[i]; Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no
>   longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins
>   instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin)); if (typeof
>   properties !== 'object' && properties !== undefined) { throw new
>   Ember.Error("Ember.Object.create only accepts objects."); } if
>   (!properties) { continue; } var keyNames = Ember.keys(properties); for
>   (var j = 0, ll = keyNames.length; j < ll; j++) { var keyName =
>   keyNames[j]; if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }
>   var value = properties[keyName], IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING; if
>   (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) { var bindings = m.bindings; if (!bindings)
>   { bindings = m.bindings = {}; } else if
>   (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) { bindings = m.bindings =
>   o_create(m.bindings); } bindings[keyName] = value; } var desc =
>   m.descs[keyName]; Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports
>   defining computed properties.", !(value instanceof
>   Ember.ComputedProperty)); Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer
>   supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value ===
>   'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));
>   Ember.assert("`actions` must be provided at extend time, not at create
>   " + "time, when Ember.ActionHandler is used (i.e. views, " +
>   "controllers & routes).", !((keyName === 'actions') &&
>   Ember.ActionHandler.detect(this))); if (concatenatedProperties &&
>   indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) { var baseValue =
>   this[keyName]; if (baseValue) { if ('function' === typeof
>   baseValue.concat) { value = baseValue.concat(value); } else { value =
>   Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value); } } else { value =
>   Ember.makeArray(value); } } if (desc) { desc.set(this, keyName,
>   value); } else { if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' &&
>   !(keyName in this)) { this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value); } else
>   if (MANDATORY_SETTER) { Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null,
>   value); // setup mandatory setter } else { this[keyName] = value; } }
>   } } } finishPartial(this, m); this.init.apply(this, arguments);
>   m.proto = proto; finishChains(this); sendEvent(this, "init"); } has no
>   method 'get'

Comment: What your test?  And MoviesController should be capitalized

Comment: MovieTracker.moviesController.get('length');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before and after a lot of trials the problem was in the controller name spelling and case. For example (based on your question code) calling:

```
MovieTracker.moviesController.get('length');
```

while the name of the controller is MoviesController with a capital M will give you this error. So try double checking your code, make sure you have the correct name with correct case.

It is also a good practice to keep controller name with capital M as @kingpin2k recommended

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as I'm following the same book as well, finally figured out why this wasn't working on Ember 1.5.1:

1. Should use capital for MoviesController instead of moviesController as mentioned.
2. Should be extending off Ember.ArrayController not creating off of it.
3. Don't use this._super()

So the following code should work for anyone interested...

```
MovieTracker.MoviesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
content: [],
init: function() {
    var list = [
        MovieTracker.Movie.create({
            title: 'Movie 1',
            rating: 4
        }),
        MovieTracker.Movie.create({
            title: 'Movie 2',
            rating: 5
        })];

    this.set('content', list);
}});
```

Answer (score -1):

`MoviesController` should be capitalized and you should be extending `Ember.ArrayController` not creating it.

```
MovieTracker.MoviesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
       content: [],
       init: function(){
           this._super();
           var list = [
               MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                   title: 'Movie 1',
                   rating: 4 }),
               MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                   title: 'Movie 2',
                   rating: 5
               })];
           this.set('content', list);
       }
});
```

Comment: Changing to extend created a new error: TypeError: Object function () { if (!wasApplied) { Class.proto(); // prepare prototype... } o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);...way too long to paste all here

Comment: please add the error to your original question, and show how you're creating the controller for the test.

Comment: I already posted how I am calling the controller from the console

Comment: Error caused by changing to .extend added to the question

Comment: You're mistaking two things here.  You should be using extend when defining a controller.  That does not create it.  So when I told you to switch to extend, that just created a new type of controller.  You still need to then create it.

Comment: I am not sure but your answer isn't clear enough, please elaborate what do you mean by creating it? Please provide simple example

Comment: I am testing from Chrome console, so I have wrote MovieTracker.MoviesController.create(); , then MovieTracker.MoviesController.get('length'); and I get the same exact error

Comment: See the .create I got from a sample from a Ember.js book, the instructions in book was to test only in Console which gave me the initial error, when I followed your instructions with .extend now I get different error. So I will appreciate it so much if you can please provide more 'console' based testing instruction as what I am trying to do here is test in console only

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47575/discussion-between-kingpin2k-and-mchan)

Answer (score -1):

'create' works perfect for the example in this book. Below code worked for me

```
MovieTracker.MoviesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
content: [],
init: function(){
var list = [    
        MovieTracker.Movie.create({
            title: 'The Avengers',
            rating: 4
        }),
        MovieTracker.Movie.create({
            title: 'Spiderman',
            rating: 5
        })];
    this.set('content', list);
}       
});
```

### versions

DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2

Ember Debugger Active VM2276:161
MovieTracker.MoviesController.get('length');

2

Comment: Can you highlight how your code is different than the code in the question? It looks the same to me.

Comment: extend 'vs' create , I used create not extend